# NSURLConnection with ARC not receiving Data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm fairly new to iOS Development and I'm trying to get content from an URL. I'm using the Apple tutorial for using NSURLConnection, everything is working but I'm not getting data. I've looked around and couldn't find an answer to my problem. I'm also using ARC in my project, maybe that causes the problem?

Here is the code I'm using, starting with my header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@end
```

implementation file:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize receivedData;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"1. viewDidLoad");
    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    // Create the connection with the request and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        NSLog(@"2. connection succeeded");
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"2. connection failed");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse     *)response
{
    NSLog(@"3. didReceiveResponse");
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"4. Connection failed! Error - %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"4. Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [receivedData length]);
}
```

All the NSLog are working, but it keeps saying receivedData has 0 bytes. I couldn't find an answer to my problem so I hope I can find my answer with this question.

Comment: ARC should not be used for Automatic Reference Counting, please read the tag wiki.

Comment: Lars, For ARC code, your `@property` should use `strong` instead of `retain`. Also, why do you not have a log statement in your `-connection :didReceiveData:` method? Andrew

Comment: I think NSURLConnection *connection was released, So you must declare it as strong property.

Answer (score 0):

I have translated the **Using NSURLConnection** part of the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) using ARC.

```
//
//  MyConnection.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyConnection : NSObject

- (void)start;

@property NSMutableData *receivedData;

@end


//
//  MyConnection.m
//

#import "MyConnection.h"

@implementation MyConnection

- (void)start {

    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // Create the connection with the request and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        // Create the NSMUtableData to fold the received data
        // ReceivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere
        _receivedData = [NSMutableData data];

    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [_receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connectionfailed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Do something with the data
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Recevied %d bytes of data", [_receivedData length]);

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completion. I've had the same problem, with cause in **threading**. If the thread that owns the `NSURLConnection` object is different than the thread that owns the `delegate`, the `delegate` will not receive notifications. That means that the error in connection would also be gone.

**So make sure you create `NSURLConnection` on same thread that you created the delegate.**

Answer (score -1):

You need to start the connection.

You could, for example, use `– initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:`.

An even smaller change to your existing code would be to just use `- start` on your connection on the if branch:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                initWithRequest:request 
                                       delegate:self 
                               startImmediately:NO
                               ];
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"2. connection succeeded");
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    [connection start];
} else {
    NSLog(@"2. connection failed");
}
```

You can find the reference manual for NSURLConnection [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: No this is incorrect, there is no need to call start. As mentioned in the manual you linked to: "This is equivalent to calling initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: and passing YES for startImmediately."

Comment: I agree, there is no need to call start if and only if you use the long version of the initializer and pass YES for startImmediately. For the sake of having a small change to the existing code I offered a second option. Indeed I have I typo in the example. Edited to fix it.

Comment: No what I'm saying is that when you use `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` as he is, there is no need to call `start`. Using the shorter initializer automatically calls the longer version with YES as startImmediately. I use NSURLConnection extensively in my code, always use the shorter initializer, and never call start. It works that way and is confirmed in the documentation that you linked to. Also as per his question, his delegate methods are being called, so the connection is obviously starting.